# else command is not being read

Tags: python, python-3.x

beginner here and I've been stuck on this for half an hour so even a badly optimized version is okay as long as it works.
While doing the fourth exercise at the end of the page [here](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/classes_and_objects_II.html) I couldn't write that function.

So I need a function that takes a point (X, Y) and determines if it is inside a rectangle I've already set the proportions for.

```
def contains(self, x, y):
    if x < self.width and x >= 0:
        if y < self.height and y >= 0:
            print("The point is in the rectangle")
        else:
            ("The point is not in the rectangle")
    else:
        ("The point is not in the rectangle")
```

Running this with a

```
r = Rectangle(Point(0, 0), 9, 3) #x, y, width, height
r.contains(74, 0)
```

does not result in anything, python just skips it.
I apologize if I missed something very clear, thanks!

Comment: You forgot to `print`.

Comment: You've left out `print` statements after both `else` statements, by the look of it

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have never felt so stupid. It worked!

Comment: BTW, `if x < self.width and x >= 0:` looks nicer like this: `if 0 <= x < self.width:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def contains(self, x, y):
    if x < self.width and x >= 0:
        if y < self.height and y >= 0:
            print("The point is in the rectangle")
        else:
            print("The point is not in the rectangle")
    else:
        print("The point is not in the rectangle")
```

i think you forgot to print as per your question reference!
if you got solution please mark as a answer :)